# Java 1.7 compatibility for a library in android studio

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I want to use [this](https://github.com/lemmingapex/trilateration) library in my android studio project but when I add it into project using gradle it show the following error

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code. This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above. If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add targetCompatibility = '1.7' sourceCompatibility = '1.7' to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

It seems it is because of java 1.7 compatablility but I have no idea how to fix it. Android studio suggests to add  targetCompatibility = '1.7' sourceCompatibility = '1.7' to that submodule's build.gradle but how can I add it into gradles dependencies section?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `VERSION_1_8` instead of `VERSION_1_7`

Install **[JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)**

You should add this

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

**FYI**

Before use **1_8** please read **[Use Java 8 Language](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#configure-gradle)**

To enable Java 8 language features and Jack for your project, enter the following in your module-level build.gradle file:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

**Clean-Rebuild** and **RUN**

Comment: Is there any drawbacks for using java 8??I mean does other dependances which now work with java 7 face any problems etc?

Comment: @MajidHojati Did't get any problem yet

Answer (score 1):

Version 52 is actually Java 8.
The library was compiled without Java 7 compatibility, so it cannot be used if you are targeting Java 7 or lower.

I see that there's an [open issue](https://github.com/lemmingapex/trilateration/issues/8) about it on their GitHub. It might be a problem with this versions only, so you might try using a previous version until they fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, Yes that issue is exactly what I have asked. Cant I download and recompile it with java 7? or divide my project to submodules and things like that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Just make sure it doesn't have any Java 8 features, like lambdas, otherwise compilation will fail. In that case you need to refactor the code as well. But I think if you try version 1.0.0 instead of 1.0.1 it will work as well.